# How can I compress a large video file as much as possible e.g. 2 GB. to 200MB?

Tags: video, compression, winrar, winzip

Recently I have received a very large 2 GB video file that was compressed to 200 MB inside a RAR file. How is this possible?

I have tried [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-highly-compress-files-using-winrar) instruction but it did not work.

The codec of the video is H264 - MPEG-4 AVC part10 avc1
Audio: mp4a Sample rate 48000 HZ and Bits per sample: 32
The following is an screenshot from the video statistics:

[image]

Comment: Video generally cannot be losslessly compressed, certainly not to that extent.

Comment: That should be an uncompressed video. What video and audio codecs does it have?

Comment: The file was a screen recording MP4 video. As written in winrar, the size of the original file is 2,341,928,765 and the packed file is 190,581,489. The extracted video is 4K and crystal clear with frame rate of 30  @golimar

Comment: Its not possible to compress a regular video file  that is already highly (lossy) compressed, such as an MP4 file, in any significant way using a lossless compression tool such as WinRAR. This was either a *very* boring video or there must be some sort of mistake. Is the video intact and complete after decompression? The Quora article you refer to seems to be misleading.

Comment: @cool That's the file format, but what about the audio and video codecs (and/or bitrates)?

Comment: ""This was either a very boring video or there must be some sort of mistake. @StarCat .. this killed me.  That is exactly what I was thinking.  Like a solid white square on a solid black background.

Comment: I added the info from VLC. @golimar

Comment: I have recieved this rar file but I can not repeat this much compression for my other videos. @SeñorCMasMas

Comment: the file does not seem to have any loss after decompression and is 2.18 GB on windows @StarCat

Comment: May be the video us encoded in an unusual way like it contains mainly key frames. As on a screen recording changes from frame to frame are often low (e.g. mouse movement) so large parts of the key frames would be identically and such a high compression rate would be feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video-files in general are NOT very compressible any further using RAR or ZIP. You may be able to shrink a 2% or 3%, but 90% as this seem to be the case here is normally impossible.
(Using a very large dictionary on the compression may help a bit, but there just is very little to gain.)

This is because a video-stream is normally already highly compressed internally and compression on top of compression doesn't gain much.
(Effectively compression removes redundant information. This is also known as removing entropy from the original data. After the compression there is very little entropy left. A second compression simply can't find any more entropy to remove.)

Now, in some cases, a video-file is stored in a form that has very little or no internal compression. In that specific case RAR or ZIP might be able to do a good job.

Screen-capture software is a prime example of software that writes its video-captures in such a low-compression method.
Screen-capture software needs to record and write to disk as quick as possible in order not to miss anything from the action on-screen and also has to do that using as little resources (CPU and RAM) as possible so as not to get in the way of what the user making the recording is doing.
That often means it sacrifices compression (which is very resource intensive and relatively slow) and it writes the video-capture with very little or no compression at all to the video-file.
Some screen-capture programs have an (optional) post-processing step to optimize (aka compress to reduce file-size), but if that is not done you have video-file that is very large, but can be compressed a great deal with RAR or ZIP, especially if you use a large dictionary as well.
(Another thing that helps with such screen-captures is that often a lot of the screen-area in the video is static, with only the mouse-pointer moving. This leads to a video that has a lot of entropy that RAR can remove.)

But it is the exception to the rule: Normally you can't (much) compress a video-file.